# Using async function inside a loop and calling a callback only after the loop has finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, syntax, callback

I'm trying to write a function that calls an async function in a loop, and only when the loop has finished, to call the callback with the result.

Something like this:

```
function foo(cb){
    var result;
    for(var i=0; i < 999; i++){
        asyncFunction(i, function(val){
            do something with result
        });
    }
    cb(result);
}
```

But I see that it gets to `cb(result);` before it actually finishes returning from all the `asyncFunction` calls.

What can be done to make it wait to finish the loop before calling `cb`? Will a promise help?

Comment: Yes. Promise is the right way

Comment: But won't I run into the same problem? What will signal the promise was fulfilled? @Rajesh

Comment: Following is a sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/o5vc1t72/) using callbacks. You have to do similar using promise

Comment: I'm afraid changing my function from a loop to recursion could cause stack overflow, the bounds of the loop can be pretty big. @Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you more:

```
function asyncFunction (callback) {
  // Do stuff
  return callback()
}

function foo () {
  var result = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < 999;) {
    asyncFunction(function () {
      i++
      result += i
    })
  }
  console.log(result)
}

foo()
```

Comment: It doesn't for me, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahrxc9gg/

Remember that if the asyncFunction needs 500ms to finish, the script will need ~8 minutes to work...

Comment: I meant when changing my actual function to work like this, maybe it's because the bounds are larger than 999 and the asyncFunction is heavier...

Comment: Probably, try to change it to 2 instead of 999, then you can verify wether or not it's because a memory leak of some sort or simply because it needs too much time.

Answer (score 1):

Async library has all the functionality you need: http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: Seems like a nice library but I prefer to not add a full library just for one function...

Comment: You don't need to add the full library, you can use ES2015 import feature and only add the functionality you need:

`$ npm install --save async-es`

`import {MODULE_YOU_NEED} from 'async-es/{MODULE_YOU_NEED}';
import async from 'async-es';`

Comment: I need this for the client side,  are you supposed to run `import {MODULE_YOU_NEED}...` in the console? Because it doesn't work in windows.

Comment: It's a ES2015 feature: https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-modules

Comment: Is there a way to bring to the browser just the part of the library that I need? (eachSeries)